# If T is self-adjoint such that $||T||<1$ exist $(I+R)^2=I+T$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following question if $T\in B(H)$ where T is self-adjoint and $||T||<1$and $H$ is Hilbert and separable, then $\exists R\in B(H)$ s.t $(I+R)^2=I+T$.

Does anyone know where to start? All I have is that $I-T$ is invertible. But I do not know how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 2):

$ \langle (I+T)x, x \rangle \geq 0$ because $- \langle Tx, x \rangle \leq \|x\|^{2}$. Every positive operator has a square root. Let $S$ be a square root of $I+T$. Take $R=S-I$.

A direct proof is obtaianed by defining $R$ explicitly as $\frac {(1/2)} 1 T+\frac {(1/2)(1/2-1)} {(1)(2)} T^{2}+\frac {(1/2)(1/2-1) (1/2-2)} {(1)(2)(3)} T^{3}+\cdots$ and verifying that $(I+R)^{2}=I+T$. This is essentialy the argument used to prove existence of square roots.

Comment: How do you know that T is compact?

Comment: You don't require compactness. See for example, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254385/square-root-of-normal-positive-operators-over-real-hilbert-spaces

Comment: Is there any other similar way to prove it since I have only proved the existence of the square root for compact and self-adjoint operators

Comment: @JhonDoe I don't think you can use theory of compact operators for this question.

Comment: Does the fact that $||f||<1$ play any role? Because we mainly focused on the theory of compact operators in class and this was a tutorial problem

Comment: @JhonDoe See my revised answer. I have defined $R$ explicitly. The verification required is somewhat tedious.

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor series for $\sqrt{1+x}$ might help, even if it is "originally" only for numbers, not operators.

Comment: Could you expound a bit more please? Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that R in this case should be $0.5T-1/8T^2+1/16T^3...$